# ZF2 oauth package documentation

Tags: oauth, zend-framework2

I just discovered thate there is a package to add oauth support on zf2 here (https://packages.zendframework.com/).
I am currently developing an API and would like to manage the authentication with oauth. However, I can't find any documentation/sample or tutorial on how to use this package.
Does anyone know where I can find some more information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [Zend Framework Introduction to OAuth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html)? The section title [Getting Started](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html#zend.oauth.introduction.getting-started) walks through some code samples while showing what needs to be don.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the documentation but if the Getting Started shows how to connect to an API using oAuth. What I actualy want is to create my own oAuth provider for my own API.